# socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python-2.7, ftp, ftplib, configparser

I'm trying to connect to my ftp server with the following Python script on a Mac running OS X Yosemite (10.10.5):

```
from ftplib import FTP
import ConfigParser

config_file = "ftp.config"
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
try:
    config.read(config_file)
except:
    raise Exception("Failed reading {} file.").format(config_file)

server_address  = config.get("main", "server")
user_name = config.get("main", "user_name")
password  = config.get("main", "password")

ftp = FTP(server_address)
ftp.login(user_name, password)
print "Logging in as '{}'".format(user_name)
```

The script gets the server information from the file "ftp.config" with the following content:

```
[main]
enable      =   1
server      =   "my.ftp.address"
user_name   =   "some_user_name"
password    =   "some_password"
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "ftp2.py", line 34, in <module>
        ftp = FTP(server_address)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 120, in __init__
        self.connect(host)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 135, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
        for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM): 
    socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I have no idea why the error occurs. I've tried to `.split()` the strings from the ".config" file, in order to remove superfluous lines, but this doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas, guys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the quotes in your configuration file

```
[main]
enable      =   1
server      =   my.ftp.address
user_name   =   some_user_name
password    =   some_password
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same `socket.gaierror` being thrown.

This caused the error:

```
companies_list = ['https://www.coinbase.com', 'https://www.glassdoor.com']
```

Removing the protocol stopped the error:

```
companies_list = ['www.coinbase.com', 'www.glassdoor.com']
```